# How do I reduce the duplicated modules in this F# code?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I'm working on a new system where I am using strongly typed Id values for my entities. To do that, I've followed a pattern that I've seen recommended before. The code seems very repetitive though and I'd like to simplify it.

```ml
type PersonId = private PersonId of string
module PersonId =
    let private prefix = "person"
    let value (PersonId id) = id
    let create (id: string) = PersonId(sprintf "%s_%s" prefix id)

type OrderId = private OrderId of string
module OrderId =
    let private prefix = "order"
    let value (OrderId id) = id
    let create (id: string) = OrderId(sprintf "%s_%s" prefix id)
```

Is there a way to make this code more generic so I don't have to repeat the module code? I was thinking of making an `EntityId` discriminated union of the `PersonId` and `OrderId` type, but not sure what the `EntityId` module code might look like. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're headed towards something like this:

```
type EntityId =
    private
    | PersonId of string
    | OrderId of string

module EntityId =
    let init makeEntity prefix =
        fun id -> makeEntity (sprintf "%s_%s" prefix id)
    let value = function
        | PersonId id
        | OrderId id -> id
```

The trick here is that the `init` function is used to make your current `create` functions, like this:

```
module PersonId =
    let create = EntityId.init PersonId "person"

module OrderId =
    let create = EntityId.init OrderId "order"
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
let personId = PersonId.create "abc"
let orderId = OrderId.create "xyz"

printfn "%A" personId
printfn "%A" orderId

printfn "%s" <| EntityId.value personId
printfn "%s" <| EntityId.value orderId
```

Output is:

```
PersonId person_abc
OrderId order_xyz
person_abc
order_xyz
```

P.S. If you like currying, you can simplify `init` to:

```
let init makeEntity prefix id =
    makeEntity (sprintf "%s_%s" prefix id)
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a good approach for now.